# Locking Records to Prevent Updates During an Account Import

Tags: php, mysql, csv, sugarcrm, suitecrm

With respect to importing records into the Accounts module from a 
CSV file, is it possible to lock certain records in the CRM database to prevent them from being updated if the import file contains erroneous old data? For example let's say that some prospects have provided correct data (ie correct cellphone, address, postal code, etc). When importing from a CSV, that account may be included in the import file with the old incorrect data that would otherwise overwrite the info already in 
SuiteCRM's database.

To prevent good data from being overwritten by a data import, I created a field named Record_Lock. Once prospects records are updated in the database, the user would enter select Yes to lock that record to prevent the record from being modified by a subsequent account import. When importing records from a CSV file, the system would check the value of Record_Lock and prevent those records from being modified. Only records with a Record_Lock field value of 'No' could be updated.

Being new to SuiteCRM and PHP, it'd be greatly appreciated if your answer would include which PHP file and directory to put the code into.  Eventually I'll get the hang of it.

Thanks for your patience and assistance.